# 2D graph calculator problems

Tags: java, optimization, graph, lwjgl

Ok so I was asked to do a 2d graph calculator as a college project, I was able to do one using java swing components and rendering an array with x,y values at real time. However there are several problems with this approach:

1. The array has a limit to the amount of values it can hold.
2. Its not very good in terms of performance because it has to loop through the whole array at 60 fps or so.

My way of fixing the first problem would be to use a dynamic array list instead of a regular array, but there is still the second problem. The idea of rendering one big image and using it as a 'map' of the graph sounds like a solution however this then brings it's own complications like:

1. What happens when the field of view goes out of the image boundaries.
2. How to know what values of the graph it should render to the image.

Now then again I face another decision making, since now we are talking more advance graphics tricks I had the idea of using lwjgl as my graphics library instead of swing which made sense from the word go, so now I can use the 3d camera system to render an orthogonal view of the 2d graph. About the first problem I thought of making chunks of image so that when we leave the FOV there is still an image to see. About the second problem am stuck, because the graph works as a function of x I don't know what my y value is until the equation has been calculated so technically I could check if the y value reaches the bottom of the image and if its lower that the top of the image (however this is still not good for performance).

Now say I have resolved all of the above there is still one last problem, and that is: because I draw the graph as very little lines (two points), how do I know how small the line have to be in order to get an accurate graph yet optimized, even when the function has some really wacky results?

Thank to everyone, and I hope you can help me :)

Comment: I'm curious over two things. 1- the quantity of data you are rendering (ie number of points) and 2- why do you need to refresh very 16 milliseconds?

Comment: 1. I would need to get all the data the image can have (withing its boundaries).
2. Because I wanted the navigation to be smooth.

Comment: @user3339838 I would just go for something, remember this is java not javascript. Its pretty fast, because this is your first time building something take a stab at it and make performance upgrades later. I did a graphing program like this in highschool and you could scroll and zoom just fine by rendering it on the fly. Just use double buffering and it will probably work pretty well.

Comment: I'm asking HOW MUCH data are you rendering? Remember, Swing uses a passive rendering engine, you don't need to repaint the UI your self at a regular interval, unless you are attempting some kind animation as well. I've been able to animate over 4500 images with only a marginal slow down in performance in real time, so I'm trying to come to grips with why your are having a problem

Comment: The amount of data is dependent on 2 things, as I said one is the size of the image and the second is how much resolution the graph should have i.e how small the lines have to be. There is no performance issues when I'm rendering a small amount of data but the problem is that I can't draw the whole graph, so when I start adding more data it starts to lag and even still the graph is not complete. My question is how I can solve this and keep my performance relatively good?